# Do content scripts live after a form submit?

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome-extension

In a Chrome Extension, do content scripts injected in a tab live after a form submit (made by the script itself) to another page via `POST` or `GET`?

Comment: As the tab reloaded so no;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the page is refreshed after submitting the form, the content scripts will be injected again.